# Can a JNLP file be "use-once"?

Tags: java, applet, java-web-start

We have an app that we use as an applet in our website. Since the latest Java updates, we can't use it because a third party component uses it's own applet loader, and that is being blocked by the runtime. So, we've moved to Webstart, which is working ok, but when a user downloads the JNLP then leaves our site they can access the app by loading the JNLP. So we miss out on the website traffic.

So my question is: is there any way to make a jnlp "use-once" to force a user to come back to the website? Tying it to a session variable? An entry in the database to say when they were last online maybe? Has anyone else done something similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Java Web Start is a deployment technology, not a marketing strategy, but some possibilities suggest themselves:

- Exploit the features of the [`<shortcut/>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) element.
- Dynamically load and display site content in your application.
- Make it easy to visit your site using the `browse()` method provided by [`java.awt.Desktop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).